# Calling a file path from the android workspace folder

Tags: android, path

Basically I have right clicked on my project name and successfully created a new folder called pdfs. I want to pre load some pdf files in here so how would I call this path/somepdffile.pdf from my mainactivity class;

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPressMe);

  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    File pdfFile = new File(Environment
      .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pdfs/2pg.pdf");

    try {
     if (pdfFile.exists()) {
      Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
      Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
      objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(objIntent);
     } else {
      Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "File NotFound",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this,
       "No Viewer Application Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       .show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });

 }

}
```

[image: explorer]

Answer (score 0):

Its better to place them in assets/ folder, that way you will be able to access them with AssetManager. Something like this

```
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "name_of_pdf_file.pdf");
    try
    {
        in = assetManager.open("name_of_pdf_file.pdf");

        in.close();
        in = null;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: you are not using the File file in your method, you are just creating it?

Comment: @raklar with this, you are getting the InputStream so you can read the file and do what you want with its content

Comment: @raklar In your case, you could write the PDF file to SDCard with an OutputStream and then pass the file path with your intent

Answer (score 0):

If you move your PDFs into `assets/`, you can use `AssetManager` to retrieve an `InputStream` for them.

If your objective is to display them in a third-party PDF viewer -- as your code would suggest -- then you can:

- Copy the PDF from the asset into external storage, in which case the rest of your code would work, or
- Copy the PDF from the asset into internal storage, then use `FileProvider` to publish it for the PDF viewer, or
- Use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to publish the PDF to the viewer app directly from assets

Coverage of `FileProvider` can be found in [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html). My `StreamProvider` is based on Google's `FileProvider` and works similarly.

Comment: can you implement it on the class above?

Answer (score 0):

Your new folder will be completely ignored by the builders. It will not be packaged with your app and copied onto any emulator or device. If you want to package data with your app, you need to use the raw or assets folders. The latter allows subfolders, so you could move your pdfs folder there.

Here's some code that will move files from `assets/pdfs` to `files/pdfs` under your app's designated external directory.

```
final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
final static int BUFF_SIZE = 2048;

private void copyPdfs() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] pdfs = null;
    try {
        pdfs = assetManager.list("pdfs");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get list of PDFs!");
    }

    File pdfDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "pdfs");
    if (!pdfDir.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating directory " + pdfDir.getAbsolutePath());
        pdfDir.mkdirs();
    }

    for (String pdf : pdfs) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Copying " + pdf);
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = assetManager.open("pdfs" + File.separator +  pdf);
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfDir, pdf));

            copyPdf(in, out);

            out.close();
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to copy PDF!");
        }
    }
}

private void copyPdf(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    out.flush();        
}
```

Comment: and how do I call it from there?

Comment: I updated my answer with some code. The files will be put into the a subdir of the app's external directory. On my device, that's "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/", but you should always use getExternalFilesDir() for access.